# Getting FBML Error unknown tag "fb:like" error with Facebook app

Tags: facebook, fbml

I've been looking at this for ages now and I cant find anything on the net that provides a solution.  When trying to use the tag...

...this is embedded on a tab canvas.  The 'Like' button appears when using the app locally, however, it doesn't appear when used on the facebook site.  I get this error:-

FBML Error (line 264): unknown tag "fb:like"

I have FBML enabled in the settings.  I've also tried using the iframe alternative with no luck.

Any ideas?

PS.. I'm using CakePHP

Comment: Ditto. This confusion with FBML, XFBML and iframe is just insane.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't seem to be available inside Canvas. According to [Facebook's document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like), there is a simple version and a version for XFBML but I can't find the document pointing to that one either. :(

The new documents is a mess.

Answer (score -1):

This is the official document about XFBML like button

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Answer (score -1):

If you're starting from scratch, you should build a [IFrame based Canvas application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) instead of a FBML based one. IFrame Canvas applications can run normal JavaScript, including the [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) which supports the `<fb:like>` tag, for example: http://apps.facebook.com/fbrelll/xfbml/fb:like.

Comment: The original poster specified they're in the tab canvas context and currently only (a subset) of FBML is available in tab canvases.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
<fb:iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true">
</fb:iframe>
</div>
```

look at this ,using fb:iframe,it works well~~have a try!

Comment: iframes are not allowed in a tab canvas for now.